# Java: Defining a generic method inside an anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class, generic-method

The following java code works fine.

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    JPanel p = (new JPanel());
    p.add( new Object(){
        JButton f(JButton x){
            x.setEnabled(false);
            return x;
        }}.f(new JButton("B")) );
    JFrame w = new JFrame("W");
    w.add(p);
    w.pack();
    w.setVisible(true);
}
```

If the method is changed to its generic form the program fails.

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    JPanel p = (new JPanel());
    p.add( new Object(){
        <T> T f(T x){
            x.setEnabled(false);
            return x;
        }}.f(new JButton("B")) );
    JFrame w = new JFrame("W");
    w.add(p);
    w.pack();
    w.setVisible(true);
}
```

Why does it fail? How can you define generic methods within an anonymous class?

This question is for learning purposes.

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: This is the error (in Intellij): Error:(11, 18) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setEnabled(boolean)
  location: variable x of type T.

Comment: A good first step would have been to copy the method into a normal, named class and ensure it compiles there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `T` generic doesn't derive explicitly from a class or an interface. So it derives from  `Object`and `Object` has no `setEnabled()` method.

If you want to use generic, you could specify a java.swing base type that has this method. For example : `javax.swing.AbstractButton`.

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    JPanel p = (new JPanel());
    p.add( new Object(){
        <T extends AbstractButton> T f(T x){
            x.setEnabled(false);
            return x;
        }}.f(new JButton("B")) );
    JFrame w = new JFrame("W");
    w.add(p);
    w.pack();
    w.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`T`'s erasure is `Object`, which does not have `setEnabled`. It works if you give it a bound of `JComponent`, which defines`setEnabled`:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    JPanel p = (new JPanel());
    p.add( new Object(){
        <T extends JComponent> T f(T x){
            x.setEnabled(false);
            return x;
        }}.f(new JButton("B")) );
    JFrame w = new JFrame("W");
    w.add(p);
    w.pack();
    w.setVisible(true);
}
```